# C++ "copy" causes exception while brute-force works fine

Tags: c++, copy

I want to put some values of an int vector into a different int vector in C++ VS2010.

At first I tried the brute force way, and it worked fine:

```
for (int i=iStartPosInDst0based;i<=(iCountSrcItemsToCopy1based);i++)
{
    uIntegers[i]=nInts[i+iFirstItemInSrcToCopy0based];
}
```

Then I wanted to get a bit more sophisticated and tried using "copy".

```
copy(nInts.begin()+iFirstItemInSrcToCopy0based, uIntegers.begin()+iCountSrcItemsToCopy1based+iFirstItemInSrcToCopy0based, uIntegers.begin() +iStartPosInDst0based);
```

But "copy" crashes.

I was really sure that my "copy" version is the same as my "brute force" version, but obviously not. But I don't see where I went wrong. Could somebody help, please?

Comment: Please show the declaration of `uIntegers` and `nInts`.

Comment: Could you have made the identifiers any longer?! :-)

Comment: That's not what brute-force means.

Comment: All this time I thought of `memcpy()` as "brute force".

Comment: Not sure if you are serious or not, but brute-force means trying out all possible values to find the solution to a problem. It has nothing to do with memory management or the straightforwardness of a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's because you call

```
copy(nInts.begin() + ..., uIntegers.begin() + ..., uIntegers.begin() + ...);
```

the second iterator should be the one of `nInts` like so

```
copy(nInts.begin() + ..., nInts.begin() + ..., uIntegers.begin() + ...);
```

Answer (score 2):

You're giving arguments to `copy` in the wrong order. The prototype is

```
std::copy(InIt first, InIt last, OutIt result)
```

Try this instead:

```
std::copy(
  nInts.begin() + iFirstItemInSrcToCopy0based
  , nInts.begin() + iFirstItemInSrcToCopy0based + iCountSrcItemsToCopy1based
  , uIntegers.begin() + iStartPosInDst0based
);
```

If you have access to C++11, you should prefer `std::copy_n`, since you have the number of elements to copy:

```
std::copy_n(
  nInts.begin() + iFirstItemInSrcToCopy0based
  , iCountSrcItemsToCopy1based
  , uIntegers.begin() + iStartPosInDst0based
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your forgot to add `iStartPosInDst0based` in the first iterator argument to `copy`:

```
copy(nInts.begin()+iStartPosInDst0based+iFirstItemInSrcToCopy0based, uIntegers.begin()+iCountSrcItemsToCopy1based+iFirstItemInSrcToCopy0based, uIntegers.begin() +iStartPosInDst0based);
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated on `cplusplus.com`

```
template <class InputIterator, class OutputIterator>
OutputIterator copy (InputIterator first, InputIterator last, OutputIterator result);
```

and

```
Output iterator to the initial position in the destination sequence.
This shall not point to any element in the range [first,last).
```

This seems to be the case here as your last parameter is similar to your second (`uIntegers`).

So it should be like

```
copy(nInts.begin()+ ..., nInts.begin()+ ..., uIntegers.begin() + );
```

See [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/copy/) for reference.